# Box-shadow в Firefox обрезается на 50px для тега button

Tags: css, firefox

Обнаружил интересный баг у Firefox (у меня версия 122.0.1 64bit). Суть в том, что элементу button невозможно установить тень шириной более 50 пикселей. Если заменить button на div - все ок, в других (Chrome, Edge) браузерах с button все ок. В принципе, как побороть понятно - обернуть button в div, но хотелось обойтись без оберток. Может быть я что-то упускаю?

Модельный код:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/234/1000/2000);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.btn {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 200vw rgb(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Hover me!</button>
```

Comment: `border: 0` решает проблему. Видимо, какая-то проблема с нативной кнопкой

Comment: @andreymal работает, спасибо. Если оформите как ответ, приму как решение.

Answer (score 0):

Да, есть такое. Добавь `transition: .1s;` или что-то свое что б пофиксить.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/234/1000/2000);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.btn {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  transition: .1s;
}

.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 200vw rgb(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Hover me!</button>
```

Comment: Наведение курсора мыши меняет стиль кнопки, а при уводе курсора браузер подвисает на полсекнуды, так что проблема фактически не решена

Comment: Возможно у меня другая версия FF под Windows. У меня наблюдаеться проблема с не полной тенью, но подвисания нету. Мне transition помог

Comment: @BlackStar1991 у меня есть подвисание. Вероятно у вас хорошая графика в компе, а у меня всего лишь встроенная. К тому же есть артефакт со стилями кнопки - `border-style` ни с того, ни с сего, становится `outset`. Неожиданный эффект.